# Deserialize non-writeable array property with Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a Class like this that I want to serialize and deserialize

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.Foo = "Foo";
testClass.Bar[0] = 3;

// to JSON
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass);
// and back
TestClass result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(json)!;

/// <summary>
/// External class that I cannot change
/// </summary>
public class TestClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public int[] Bar { get; } = new int[3];
}
```

Serializing works well, but at deserializing "Bar" is not writeable, so skipped and has default values.
Is there a way to tell Json.net to deserialize element by element of the (maybe reaonly arrays?) array and set it as value for the corresponding array index?

Comment: Two approaches come to my mind: (1) Declare a constructor in TestClass (which can be private when used in conjunction with the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute) that allows the derserializer to pass the deserialized array into the TestClass instance. You would then also need to declare a public parameter constructor as well. (2) Use a List<int> instead of int\[\]. Up to you to select the one that is a better match with regard to the overall code design of your project...

Comment: I have no chance to change TestClass. It's part of an external lib

Comment: Alright. Then i would agree with the suggestion as given in the answer by BWA below. (My apologies for overlooking the respective code comment in your code example earlier.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
    var jsonObj=JObject.Parse(json);
    TestClass result=jsonObj.ToObject<TestClass>();

    for (var i=0; i <  ((JArray) jsonObj["Bar"]).Count; i++)
        result.Bar[i]= (int) jsonObj["Bar"][i];
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for this simple example I have a solution. Has to be tested on more complex structures.

```
public class TestConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private bool skipOnce = false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (skipOnce)
        {
            skipOnce = false;
            return false;
        }

        return objectType.GetProperties().Any(prop => !prop.CanWrite && prop.PropertyType.IsArray);
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        skipOnce = true; // our manual serializer.Deserialize will cause endless recursion otherwise

        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        reader = jo.CreateReader(); // reset reader
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);

        var readOnlyArrayProperties = objectType.GetProperties().Where(prop => !prop.CanWrite && prop.PropertyType.IsArray);
        foreach (var readOnlyProperty in readOnlyArrayProperties)
        {
            var readOnlyArray = (Array)readOnlyProperty.GetValue(obj)!;
            Type elementType = readOnlyArray.GetType().GetElementType()!;
            var jsonArrayProp = (JArray)jo[readOnlyProperty.Name]!;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < readOnlyArray.Length; i++)
            {
                readOnlyArray.SetValue(jsonArrayProp[i].ToObject(elementType, serializer), i);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Basic idea: If we have readonly array properties in the current object we do serializer.Deserialize manually and additionaly we set the value for every array index.

[EDIT] After test with complex structure: Seems to be more complicated. Sometimes `existingValue`is set. In these cases json.net seems to ignore our returned obj. populating into `existingValue` seems to work at first glance.